# PHP running Union All SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im trying to combine two tables together, but whenever i run the program, this happens.
[image]

As you can see i've echoed out the sql statement. Here are my codes.

```
$queryc1 = "select sum(repeater),sum(membersigned) from sales UNION ALL select count(*) from approach;"; //DO INNERJOIN PRACTISE
$resultc1 = mysqli_query($dbconn,$queryc1);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Repeater</th>
<th>Members</th>
<th>Approach</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc1)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sum(repeater)'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sum(membersigned)'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['count(*)'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo $queryc1;
```

I'd like to show count(*) as in the photo, as a third column to the genrated table.

Comment: No results for your query! that is the reason of showing warning, try to run the query on phpmyadmin and confirm there are results are there are not

Comment: Union queries must have the same number of columns. Your queries have 2 and 1 column as result.

Comment: @MohammadFareed Yes, i've tried that but it only outputs the sum(repeater) and sum(member) but not the count(*)

Comment: @juergend uhmm, i've tried to make it to 1 column:1 column but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need UNION select here, instead you can use subquery:

```
select sum(repeater) as repeater_sum,
       sum(membersigned) as membersigned_sum,
       (select count(*) from approach) as approach_count
from sales;
```

and in PHP you use `$row['repeater_sum']`.. etc

Comment: Thanks it works!! I was always weak with subqueries haha didnt think of using this

Comment: Welcome, yeah it's OKay you just need more time to practice. Soon u'll become pro, I'm sure

Answer (score 2):

When you union two or more queries together each query should have the same columns of data with same data type for example :

```
SELECT SUM(repeater),SUM(membersigned) FROM sales
UNION
SELECT Text1,Text2 FROM approach
```

Replace your query with this format

Comment: Oh i see now im getting an output. However, i would like there to be 3 columns to the table generated, and not only 2 columns. How do i do it? Is using Union the correct way? Previously i did it by joining 2 tables with e.g where s.username=a.username but it didn't work